# Consider following code with anchor tag

Tags: php, html

```
<div class="pricing-item" id="price">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo WEB;?>img/dish/dish3.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="pricing-item-details">
        <h3><b>Mutter Paneer Masala</b></h3>
        <p>Vegetarian north Indian dish consisting of peas and paneer in a tomato based sauce, spiced with garam masala.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="1">Add to Cart</a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <!--price tag-->
    <span class="hot-tag br-red" id="price_no">₹ 126</span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I want is that when i click on Add to cart i want to post name and price of product to controller in codeigniter.
This content is static. so please tell me how should i post this content and i have many products.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that the content is static, here's a sample of solution I can think based on the information and code snippet you have provided:

```
<div class="pricing-item" id="price">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo WEB;?>img/dish/dish3.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="pricing-item-details">
        <h3><b>Mutter Paneer Masala</b></h3>
        <p>Vegetarian north Indian dish consisting of peas and paneer in a tomato based sauce, spiced with garam masala.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-danger add-cart">Add to Cart</button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <!--price tag-->
    <span class="hot-tag br-red" id="price_no">₹ <span class="product-price">126</span></span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="pricing-item" id="price">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo WEB;?>img/dish/dish3.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="pricing-item-details">
        <h3><b>Product 2</b></h3>
        <p>My second product.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-danger add-cart">Add to Cart</button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <!--price tag-->
    <span class="hot-tag br-red" id="price_no">₹ <span class="product-price">1000</span></span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

// And more products...

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add-cart').on('click', function () {
            var productName = $(this).closest('.pricing-item').find('h3 > b').text();
            var productPrice = $(this).closest('.pricing-item').find('.product-price').text();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    name: productName,
                    price: productPrice,
                },
                dataType: 'json',
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will post the product **name** and **price** using ajax.

But I highly recommend to display the product list dynamically from the database and maybe just add a data attribute of the product ID and post that ID instead of the static name and price. Then let the backend(codeigniter) side handle fetching the correct product name and price from the database based on the product ID.